# Unable to enter in the 'commenter' field of my database after executing my sql query, all the other fields are set except the said field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database having this schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment`
(
`comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`commenter` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`time` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;
```

and i have a following code snippet in PHP

```
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$dbNmee = $_SESSION['user'];
$time=date("h:i:sA",strtotime("+0 minute"));
$date=date("d-m-y",strtotime("+0 minute"));
$sql="INSERT INTO comment (commenter , comment , time , date) VALUES    ('$dbNmee','$comment','$time','$date')";
```

but am unable to enter in the commenter field of my database.

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded? It's required when using sessions. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, you are connected to DB, *right?*

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: What does "_unable to enter in the commenter field of my database_" mean? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening now? Be sure to include any error messages do you receive.

Comment: Yup you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks and that query should be like  
"INSERT INTO comment (commenter , comment , time , date) VALUES    ('".$dbNmee."','".$comment."','".$time."','".$date."')"

Comment: @GeorgeCummins *"As a freebie: 'comment' is a MySQL reserved word."* - [No it isn't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: first of all ..try asking questions more properly..

Comment: The above code worked when I tested it, replacing the $_POST & $_SESSION variables with constant values. Check the $_POST and $_SESSION variables.

Comment: @George Cummins I am not receiving any error message, the problem is that after executing my script all the fields in my database are set according to the passed value but the 'commenter' field remains blank or empty, i dn't know why is it happening

Comment: @Marc B "The script is running on the intranet so i am  not paying that much attention to the security right now, but thanks for pointing it out"

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['comment']` according to `print_r($_POST)`? With regards to security, be aware that breaches from within are far more common than most people realize.

Comment: @SUNNYben "Yeah it works for constant value in the 'commenter' field but i want it to work for a variable"

Comment: @all "check the link to know what actually is happening" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8igtgI_vPMtOWNLam5TV2tFTzA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please consider posting relevant data in the question here, instead of at the other end of a link. Links rot, and when that happens the question cannot help future site visitors.